# Prevent creation of foreign keys in mapping tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How do we prevent the creation of foreign keys in hibernate ?
I need to insert some childs into my "oneToMany" relationship which do not exist yet. Hibernate should just ignore the fact that the childs do not exist yet.

Currently i receive a foreign key exception once i try to insert those non existing childs. So i need to disable the foreign key creation/useage.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
public class Chunk extends HibernateComponent{

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    public Set<Identity> inChunk = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Transient
    public Set<ChunkLoader> loadedBy = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Chunk() {}
    public Chunk(int x, int y, Date createdOn) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

How do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution... instead of letting hibernate create the join table completly by yourself you can modify the creation with "JoinTable".

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "chunk", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"x", "y"})}, indexes = {@Index(columnList = "x,y")})
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
public class Chunk extends HibernateComponent{

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {})
    @JoinTable(name = "chunk_identity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "identity_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    public Set<Identity> inChunk = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Transient
    public Set<ChunkLoader> loadedBy = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Chunk() {}
    public Chunk(int x, int y, Date createdOn) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

This way we can define if we need an foreign key or if we can simply ignore it.